# Google maps javascript example not working

Tags: google-maps

I am using the example from the google maps website.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

I am posting the entire code below. I get a blank screen - nothing seems to show up either on firefox or chrome. Can anyone suggest what is going on?

Thank you,
-VJ

---

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out the problem. I was saving the code in an html file using wordpad and saving it in format Unicode. When I saved the file using notepad and format ANSI, everything is ok. Took me the entire morning to figure this out!!!